# Getting empty object in REST service in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-ws

I'm having following method in my resource class for a REST service in Java.

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Player createCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    System.out.println("Request for Create");

    System.out.println(""+customer.getID()+"\n"+customer.getTableID()+"\n"+customer.getCustNick());

    //Above statement should print the details I send via JSON object

    //return custdao.create(customer); //Want to call this to add new "customer"  into database table.

    return player;
}
```

And following the jQuery method I call when input fields  in the form are filled and create button is clicked.

```
function createEntry() {
        var formData = JSON.stringify({
            "ID" : $("input[name='txtID']").val(),
            "tableID" : $("input[name='txtTableID']").val(),
            "custNick" : $("input[name='txtNick']").val()
        });

        console.log(formData); //Just to see if form details are JSON encoded.

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: baseURL,
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Customer Added!");
                $("div.response").append("<h3>New Customer ("+ $("input[name='txtNick']").val() +") Added on the Server</h3>");
            }
        });
    }
```

But on server, I'm getting empty "customer" object, what am I doing wrong here? Please  let me know if you need any further details (regarding Customer class model).

**Update:** Following is Customer class.

```
/*ignore imports, all required imports are included */

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer
{
    private int id;
    private int tableid;
    private String custnick;

    public int getID()
    {
            return id;
    }

    public void setID(int id)
    {
            this.id = id;
    }

    ....
    ....
    /* Similar Setter-Getter Methods for the fields */
}
```

I guess the problem has something to do with XML schema of my "Customer" class and the node names I send in JSON object is not matching with schema that's why it may not be able to map fields with setter methods of my model class, not sure though.

Comment: Instead of manually creating the form data, try using `jQuery('#formID').serializeArray();`

Comment: Can you post the Customer class? Does it work with XML?

Comment: @ShaggyInjun: I can `serializeArray()` but the servuce is not supposed be used via HTML, I'll be creating Java client (using Apache HTTP Client) to consume the service, so the markup is very basic and I haven't used any form tag.

Comment: @Tom: It does return the data successfully upon GET request as JSON object.

Comment: @Kush so it only fails when you construct the JSON object in your JavaScript function. Right? Please show us the annotated entity class for Customer.

Comment: @Tom: Class details added, I can `console.log` the constructed JSON object in the browser, and even `$.ajax()` runs with success but on the server-end, I get empty customer object.

Comment: You have mismatch on attributes and setters. IMO the parser might be expecting strict camelcase.

Also your keys in json are different from class attribute names. Are you using the same keys when calling the service from a httpclient like Fiddler ( I think you mentioned you are able to call get successfully. )

I would make sure that to log the request object to look at the keys.
I think you are looking at the output of `System.out.println(""+customer.getID()+"\n"+customer.getTableID()+"\n"+customer.getCustNick());`. Server will tell you exactly what you are getting from client.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun: I've method names that follow Java conventions but field names are all in small letters as shown in entity class, is there any way I can modify names used in XML schema created from entity class?

Comment: @Kush you can change a fied name using the @ XmlElement annotation: http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_7_1-Annotations-for-Fields.html#Annotations%20for%20Fields

Comment: @Tom: I went through the link, easy enough to understand, post the link as answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by a field name mismatch.

You can use the `@XmlElement` JAXB annotation on your entity class to set whatever names you want for your fields to make it all clear. Just follow this link: http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_7_1-Annotations-for-Fields.html#Annotations%20for%20Fields